# Animate and then replace the class of div with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

**JSFiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harmeet_jaipur/zcYLM/)**

The way it is supposed to work is as follows:

1 - the red blocks slide from top to bottom 
2 - once that is done then the red boxes fadeOut
3 - then blue boxes fadeIn

Following is the html :

```
<div class="posRel">
    <div class="trans1"></div>
    <div class="trans2"></div>
    <div class="trans3"></div>
    <div class="trans4"></div>
    <div class="trans5"></div>
    <div class="trans6"></div>
    <div class="trans7"></div>
</div>
```

Following is the js :

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        $('.trans' + i).toggleClass('toggle');
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.toggle').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).addClass('fSmall1').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }, 2000);
```

<s>Link to the project: `http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/team/design/EO/page-2.html`</s>

**Link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harmeet_jaipur/zcYLM/)**

Issues that i am facing :

- fadeOut and fadeIn are not working
- anything better than settimeout to do this?

I am rather inexperienced when it comes to js/jQuery so feel free to point out any silly mistake(s) too. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a proper link to your test-case (in a jsfiddle for example). SO doesn't allow numeric urls (IPs).

Comment: Are you not able to access that link ?

Comment: I'm sure able to copy and paste it, but it's not clickable, because you have formatted it as code, because SO doesn't allow these kind of links (which you have noticed).

Comment: I'm checking your project in Chrome and it seems to work. What browser are you testing?

Comment: It is the ftp that i am assigned at work and i do not have any other way to provide you with the link than posting it as a code. If you can access then what seems to be the issue ?

Comment: maqjav, i am testing it in chrome too. The oranges that arrive have strings below them, when they come into the tree, the strings just vanish, i need it to fadeOut.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI at all?

Comment: @ Derek : No, just jQuery 1.9

Comment: Ah. jQueryUI adds animations to the toggleClass() function that make it quite easy to do what you want. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and attack most of your problems in one hit, but I suspect we may need a little back and forth to completely solve it.

Firstly, your fade in / out issue is tied to the way your animation is being fired. You're essentially calling the fade out on every element individually and then the fade in, but from the functionality you described in your requirements you should be firing one fade on the container instead:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    $('.trans' + i).toggleClass('toggle');
}

setTimeout(function () {
    $('.posRel').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('.toggle').addClass('fSmall1');
        $('.posRel').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}, 2000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcYLM/7/)

**Smooth Transition**

If you'd like to have a smooth fade without it blinking out and then back in you can use the [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method instead. A FadeTo() example can be found below, this will have all of the shapes fall down, pause for a fraction of a second, and then change colour. You can experiment with removing the setTimeout now that the fadeTo controls the animation time, but I've left it as close to the original as possible.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    $('.trans' + i).toggleClass('toggle');
}

setTimeout(function () {
    $('.posRel').fadeTo('slow', 2, function () {$('.toggle').addClass('fSmall1');});
}, 2000);
```

[fadeTo() Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcYLM/12/)

Comment: Good solution, one issue though, if you go visit the project link that i posted, then you will see that now the images vanish and then new ones fade in. Can you tell me a way where first dissolves into second?

Comment: Absolutely,  see my comment regarding the fadeTo method above, I'll post a new fiddle soon

Comment: Updated the js to include a fadeTo() Example Fiddle which should behave as you want.

Comment: Now it is back to original, as in fade effect is gone, on my project link i mean. :/ I apologise for being such naive about this.

Comment: The code on your site is a bit different to my example above, but the same rules apply. The problem that you have with the code on your site is the mis-matched timeout/fade values. Try my smooth transition example and see if that helps, it's timeout / fade values work very nicely.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the fade time values are in milliseconds, meaning the value on your site of 10 will be 10 milliseconds. If you want the first way I've shown to work you need to make that value larger, say 1500 (1.5 seconds).

Comment: The transition is set to 2 seconds and the timeout function is at 2000. Is that what you meant when you were talking about mismatch ?

Comment: No sorry, I meant on your fadeIn/fadeOut, they're both set to 10 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQueryUI, this will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcYLM/11/ (this is an updated one)

This is a basic, stripped down example of your problem, but you can apply it to your code.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[class*=trans]')
        .toggleClass('toggle', 2000)
        .promise()
        .done(function() {
            $(this)
                .fadeOut(2000)
                .promise()
                .done(function() { 
                    $(this)
                        .addClass('blue')
                        .fadeIn(2000);
                });
        });
});
```

CSS:

```
.posRel {
    position:relative;
}

div.posRel > div {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

div.posRel > div.trans1 { left:-50px; }
div.posRel > div.trans1.toggle { left:100px; top:150px; }
div.posRel > div.blue { background-color:blue; }
```

Comment: Hmm, i am avoiding jQuery Ui at the moment but if i have no option left then i will consider this solution, thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 1):

i had used fadeto property, try the link. http://jsfiddle.net/zcYLM/10/

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/zcYLM/10/][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/zcYLM/10/
```